# Embed Cefsharp browser in Custom Task Pane for Excel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vsto, cefsharp

As the headline suggests, what I'm trying to do is to embed a [Cefsharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp) Chromium browser in a VSTO Custom Task Pane (CTP) for Excel.
I have tested the Cefsharp browser in a standard Windows form and it works beautifully. And I'm using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608590.aspx) code for the CTP, and that also works without problems.
The problem arise when I try to combine them. Then I get an 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' error stating that  'CefSharp.Core.DLL' could not be read.

My CTP startup-function loos like this:

```
Private taskPaneControl1 As TaskPaneControl
Private WithEvents taskPanaValue As CustomTaskPane

Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    taskPaneControl1 = New TaskPaneControl()
    taskPanaValue = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneControl1, "TEST")
    taskPanaValue.Width = 650
End Sub
```

...and it works as fine as long as I just have an 'empty' constructor in TaskPaneControl:

```
Public Class TaskPaneControl
    Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser, chrome_popup As ChromiumWebBrowser
    Private proc As New Process

    Public Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

        'Dim settings As New CefSettings
    End Sub
End Class
```

...but when I un-comment "Dim settings As New CefSettings" in the bottom of the constructor I get the 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'-error mentioned above.
Cefsharp is installed via Nuget Package Manager and all references are correctly set.

**I don't understan why it's not working?!**

Setup:

- Windows 10 64-bit
- Excel 2016 32-bit
- VS 2015
- Cefsharp 57.0

Comment: CefSharp isn't suited to being used with Excel. Try CefGlue or ChromiumFx

Comment: See my detailed answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077862/4583726