# CefSharp in VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, cefsharp, excel-addins

I'm trying to use CefSharp WindowForm Control in the VSTO Excel Addin. The CefSharp.WinForms version is 75.1.142 and I'm making an addin on Excel 2013 (64 Bit) through VS 2017.

I'm getting FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp, Version=75.1.142.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
    on the below code execution.

```
    public void InitBrowser()
    {
        var cefSettings = new CefSettings();
        cefSettings.MultiThreadedMessageLoop = true;
        // I'm setting current directory to D:\\CEF\\cefsharp\\ExcelWinform\\ExcelWinformAddIn\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\ where all the CefSharp dlls and dependencies are present.
        cefSettings.BrowserSubprocessPath = "D:\\CEF\\cefsharp\\ExcelWinform\\ExcelWinformAddIn\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe";

        if (!Cef.Initialize(cefSettings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null))
        {
            throw new Exception("Unable to Initialize Cef");
        }

        browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("http://www.google.com");
        {
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        BrowserSettings browserSettings = new BrowserSettings();
        //browserSettings.FileAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        //browserSettings.UniversalAccessFromFileUrls = CefState.Enabled;
        browserSettings.BackgroundColor = 0xFFFF00;
        browserSettings.LocalStorage = CefState.Enabled;// enable Local access
        browser.BrowserSettings = browserSettings;
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }

If instead of VSTO Excel addin, I just create a simple WindowFrom application then the abve code is working fine.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48630473/embed-cefsharp-browser-in-custom-task-pane-for-excel#comment84261436_48630473

Answer (score 9):

Using `CefSharp` **directly** in an `Office VSTO` plugin/addin is not supported.

> If multiple VSTO Add-ins are installed for an application, each VSTO Add-in is loaded in a different application domain.

As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/architecture-of-vsto-add-ins?view=vs-2019 `Office VSTO` will load your `add-in` using as `AppDomain` (I believe even if you only load a single add-in the non-default appdomain will be used).

`CefSharp` is built using `VC++` which cannot be loaded in the non-default `AppDomain`. The error you are seeing is related to the plugin being unable to load `libcef.dll`, you could resolve this issue, only to be faced with `Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains`.

You can run `CefSharp` out of process, for which there is an example. It's a little outdated, the fundamentals should still be relevant. See https://github.com/stever/AppHostCefSharp

My personal recommendation is to use [CefGlue](https://gitlab.com/xiliumhq/chromiumembedded/cefglue) which is `P/Invoke` based so use a fundamentally different approach to interacting with the unmanaged `libcef.dll`.

For an alternative to VSTO that is compatible with CefSharp check out [NetOffice](https://netoffice.io/)

---

See also

- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1191
- https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/351
- [How to use Cefsharp browser control in ExcelDNA add-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710822/cefsharp-in-exceldna)
- [Cannot pass a GCHandle across AppDomains: solution without delegates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118047/cannot-pass-a-gchandle-across-appdomains-solution-without-delegates)
- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/169359/ccli-dll-is-initialized-in-wrong-appdomain.html

Comment: For reference I am the `Maintainer` of the `CefSharp` project, at time of writing the answer has at least one downvote. I understand people may not like the answer, it is however technically correct.