# Using CefSharp with introp to embed in Microsoft Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have built new C# class library (user control) using CefSharp (it compiles with no errors) to use it in ms access form but when I try to embed in the form i get the following error:

[image]

and did not get error all the times, sometimes works fine, and when I try to embed in excel and I get this error:

[image]

I developed this library using:

- Visual Studio 2013
- Dot Net Framework 4.5.2
- CefSharp 53.0.0

and this is the main part of my code:

```
public void InitBrowser()
    {
        var settings = new CefSettings();
        string assemblyFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        if (!Cef.IsInitialized)
        {
            settings.BrowserSubprocessPath = Path.Combine(assemblyFolder, "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe");
            if (Cef.Initialize(settings))
            {
                browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("url");
            }
        }
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
        browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    }
```

What is the problem in this scenario?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using CefSharp in Access is not supported see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58077862/4583726

Comment: Thank you for your reply, could you suggest good working alternatives?

Comment: You can try CefGlue see https://gitlab.com/xiliumhq/chromiumembedded/cefglue/-/issues/30#note_246723955 for link to Nuget packages

Comment: Ok, Thank you for your suggestions.